# Reading a file into a struct array

Tags: c++, arrays, file, struct

Having troubles reading a file into a struct without eof. I have all of the needed includes in my .h file and I am getting an error that says "IntelliSense: no operator ">>" matches these operand"

```
struct Courses
{
    string mCourseID;
    double mCourseNumber;
    double mMaxCapacity;
    double mCurrentEnroled;
};

Courses addCourse(istream &File);


Courses addCourse(istream &File)
{
    Courses sData;

    File >> sData.mCourseID;
    File >> sData.mCourseNumber;
    File >> sData.mCurrentEnroled;
    File >> sData.mMaxCapacity;

    return sData;
 }

void readCourses(Courses sCourses[], ifstream &File, int &numCourses)
{
    while (addCourse(File) >> sCourses[numCourses])
    {

        numCourses++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is it OK to change `addCourse()`'s prototype?

Comment: man, this program is so academic, so many things could go wrong that they don't expect you to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you want to change the signature of `addCourse` to this...

```
istream& addCourse(istream &File, Courses& sData)
{
    File >> sData.mCourseID;
    File >> sData.mCourseNumber;
    File >> sData.mCurrentEnroled;
    File >> sData.mMaxCapacity;

    return File;
}
```

Then, modify your other function with these modifications...

```
void readCourses(Courses sCourses[], ifstream &File, int &numCourses)
{
    while (addCourse(File, sCourses[numCourses]))
    {
        numCourses++;
    }
 //......
```

But again, is your array `sCourses` big enough to hold as many `Courses` you will input? Or will you put a stopping condition? ...rethink your program logic.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much! The limit will be ten courses, it should be fine!